# Merging JS files using Shrinksafe

Tags: javascript, dojo

Dear All,
I need to merge all the JavaScript files inside one folder to a single file using Shrinksafe.
I'm using the following ANT script for that. But this is not working fine.

```
<!-- Merge the JS files in scripts folder to a single file-->
<target name="mergegp-js">
    <echo message="Starting Merging"/>          
    <java fork="true" dir="${shrinksafe.util.path}/buildscripts" classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main">
        <classpath>
           <pathelement location="${shrinksafe.util.path}/shrinksafe/js.jar"/>
           <pathelement location="${shrinksafe.util.path}/shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar"/>
           <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
         </classpath>
         <arg value="build.js"/>
         <arg value="${merged.gpstatic.folder}/test/scripts/*.js > tempMerged.js"/>
   </java>
   <echo message="js build successfull." />
</target>
```

But the above script is giving me the following error.

```
[java] js: "jslib/buildUtil.js", line 1168: exception from uncaught JavaScript throw: Malformed name/value pair: [C:/Test/scripts/*.js]. Format should be name=value
```

Can someone please guide me to fix this issue.?

Comment: Have you JSLinted your JS code? Are you sure it's not malformed?

Comment: jslib/buildUtils.js is a standard build script in the Dojo Toolkit.  I can attest that it doesn't have JavaScript syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments to `build.js` should be in format `name=value`. For example, `profile=standard action=release`. You need to change the syntax of the argument to match the format. So the line after

```
<arg value="build.js"/>
```

should be like:

```
<arg value="profile=standard action=release" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to compress the file without using build.js?

Comment: If you want to use Shrinksafe, ``build.js`` is the actual script that does the work. So you need to use it. But I think you can use other tools, e.g. simple Ant script or Google Closure compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is valid XML:

```
<arg value="${merged.gpstatic.folder}/test/scripts/*.js > tempMerged.js"/>
```